# Install ubuntu with uefi enabled on positivo bgh notebook

Tags: 14.04, uefi

Hello everyone I am Nicolas I am from Uruguay a few months ago I got a positive notebook bgh with a modified ubuntu 14.04 is very heavy for that pc so I want to install an original one but it has uefi activated on the bios and it does not allow to deactivate it and I wanted to ask if there is any Way to solve the problem, if they have any solution or something I would appreciate it,And I do not speak much English so I use the google translate

Comment: What OS you want to install on your laptop?

Comment: I want to install ubuntu 16.04

Comment: or ubuntu 14.04

Comment: If the Ubuntu you complain about now was factory installed, what reason you could possibly have to think reinstalling the same (or 16.04) will make any difference? Unless you've done something to it and now installing from scratch seems a reasonable (and faster) option... Otherwise you should expect pretty much the same performance. And UEFI has nothing to do with it and you can and should install in UEFI mode anyway. For better results edit your question and post hardware specs. We don't know about Positivo's notebooks.